# How to generate a complex json file from excel worksheet

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an excel file with few columns. I want to write a react
application that will upload/open the excel file, retrieve the data
row by row and generate a complex json file and store it on a server.
I have the schema of what the json file will look like.
How do I start the generation of this json file? Is it also better to
do this on the client side or server side? I am using json.net and new to this.

Comment: I would say that the best option would be to just upload the excel file to server, read it contents with corresponding library into your class structure and then serialize it with json library of your choice.

Comment: I am not clear about how to do the json serialize for a nested json file. If I have a json schema, is there a way to say use this schema or I will need to code that manually?

Comment: What is nested json file in this context? Where it came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you look into using the [EPPlus library](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) with the [Newtonsoft Json.NET library](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json).

You can [read a file upload directly into an Excel package](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/277/reading-excel-files-without-saving-to-disk-in-asp-net) without saving anything to disk, extract the data you need by reading the Excel Worksheet and then create a [generic List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) of a custom class that represents the data you want to serialize, then serialize that list into JSON using [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).